# gitlab-ci if with string not working properly?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I need to compare a string, but I can't. basically I'm retrieving the last pipeline execution status and need to do something according to it, this is my script code :

```
- |
  LAST_EXEC=$(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXXXXX" "https://xxxxx" | jq -r .[1].status)
- echo "content of LAST_EXEC=${LAST_EXEC}"
- >
  if ["$LAST_EXEC" == "success"]; then
    echo "we have a success"
  else
    echo "we do NOT have a success"
  fi
```

I've comfirmed that I have "success" in `LAST_EXEC` (with the echo just before the if) but the if always go into "we do NOT have success"

I tried with

```
if ["$LAST_EXEC" == "success"]
if [$LAST_EXEC == success]
if [$LAST_EXEC == "success"]
if ["$LAST_EXEC" == success]
if ["${LAST_EXEC}" == "success"]
if [${LAST_EXEC} == success]
if [${LAST_EXEC} == "success"]
if ["${LAST_EXEC}" == success]
```

the comparaison never works, (and I don't understand why we might need quote).

Would anyone have a solution for this trivial issue?

Thanks.

Comment: That's strange, can you try this: `- if ['$LAST_EXEC == "success"']`? You might have to use single quotes

Comment: apparently I was missing a spaces (see my awnser)

Comment: very strange... but cool that it's working now :)

Answer (score 2):

this one is working if `[ $LAST_EXEC == "success" ]` the difference is the spaces

`[$LAST_EXEC == "success"]` will not work

`[ $LAST_EXEC == "success" ]` will work

Even the spaces around the `==` are important, if you write `[ $LAST_EXEC=="success" ]` it will ALWAYS be true